# Sorting Complex Numbers

Tags: c#, sorting, struct

I have a struct called "Complex" in my project (I build it with using C#) and as the name of the struct implies, it's a struct for complex numbers. That struct has a built-in method called "Modulus" so that I can calculate the modulus of a complex number. The things are quite easy up to now.

The thing is, I create an array out of this struct and I want to sort the array according to the modulus of the complex numbers contained.(greater to smaller). Is there a way for that?? (Any algorithm suggestions will be welcomed.)

Thank you!!

Comment: would you provide sample? sample unsorted array and after sorting this array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Complex[] complexArray = ...

Complex[] sortedArray = complexArray.OrderByDescending(c => c.Modulus()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Short, simple, and to the point (though it may actually be a method call - since they stated that `Modulus` is a "built-in method").

Comment: Too much linq :) this is very slow and resource consuming than using an IComparer!

Comment: @SalvatorePreviti - LINQ may be more clever than you are giving it credit for. For example, it will cache the computed Modulus values. There is no way to know which one is more performant without trying both ways against a very large data set.

Comment: You can actually be right, but of course at least only if you compare the squared modulus. Floating point operation involving only sum and multiplication usually are very fast and can be optimized quite a lot by JIT. Squared root involves more time consuming computation.

Comment: This method consumes more memory and can be less cache efficient for very big numbers of n due to more memory involved (more cache miss).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can increase performances comparing squared modulus instead of modulus.
You don't need the squared root: "sqrt( a * a + b * b ) >= sqrt( c * c + d * d )" is equivalent to "a * a + b + b >= c * c + d * d".

Then, you can write a comparer to sort complex numbers.

```
public class ComplexModulusComparer :
    IComparer<Complex>,
    IComparer
{
    public static readonly ComplexModulusComparer Default = new ComplexModulusComparer();

    public int Compare(Complex a, Complex b)
    {
        return a.ModulusSquared().CompareTo(b.ModulusSquared());
    }

    int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        return ((Complex)a).ModulusSquared().CompareTo(((Complex)b).ModulusSquared());
    }
}
```

You can write also the reverse comparer, since you want from greater to smaller.

```
public class ComplexModulusReverseComparer :
    IComparer<Complex>,
    IComparer
{
    public static readonly ComplexModulusReverseComparer Default = new ComplexModulusReverseComparer();

    public int Compare(Complex a, Complex b)
    {
        return - a.ModulusSquared().CompareTo(b.ModulusSquared());
    }

    int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        return - ((Complex)a).ModulusSquared().CompareTo(((Complex)b).ModulusSquared());
    }
}
```

To sort an array you can then write two nice extension method ...

```
public static void SortByModulus(this Complex[] array)
{
    Array.Sort(array, ComplexModulusComparer.Default);
}

public static void SortReverseByModulus(this Complex[] array)
{
    Array.Sort(array, ComplexModulusReverseComparer.Default);
}
```

Then in your code...

```
Complex[] myArray ...;
myArray.SortReverseByModulus();
```

You can also implement the IComparable, if you wish, but a more correct and formal approach is to use the IComparer from my point of view.

```
public struct Complex :
    IComparable<Complex>
{
    public double R;
    public double I;

    public double Modulus() { return Math.Sqrt(R * R + I * I); }

    public double ModulusSquared() { return R * R + I * I; }

    public int CompareTo(Complex other)
    {
        return this.ModulusSquared().CompareTo(other.ModulusSquared());
    }
}
```

And then you can write the ReverseComparer that can apply to every kind of comparer

```
public class ReverseComparer<T> :
    IComparer<T>
{
    private IComparer<T> comparer;

    public static readonly ReverseComparer<T> Default = new ReverseComparer<T>();

    public ReverseComparer<T>() :
        this(Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public ReverseComparer<T>(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    public int Compare(T a, T b)
    {
        return - this.comparer.Compare(a, b);
    }
}
```

Then when you need to sort....

```
Complex[] array ...;
Array.Sort(array, ReverseComparer<Complex>.Default);
```

or in case you have another IComparer...

```
Complex[] array ...;
Array.Sort(array, new ReverseComparer<Complex>(myothercomparer));
```

RE-EDIT-

Ok i performed some speed test calculation.
Compiled with C# 4.0, in release mode, launched with all instances of visual studio closed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestComplex
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct Complex
        {
            public double R;
            public double I;

            public double ModulusSquared()
            {
                return this.R * this.R + this.I * this.I;
            }
        }

        public class ComplexComparer :
            IComparer<Complex>
        {
            public static readonly ComplexComparer Default = new ComplexComparer();

            public int Compare(Complex x, Complex y)
            {
                return x.ModulusSquared().CompareTo(y.ModulusSquared());
            }
        }

        private static void RandomComplexArray(Complex[] myArray)
        {
            // We use always the same seed to avoid differences in quicksort.
            Random r = new Random(2323);
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; ++i)
            {
                myArray[i].R = r.NextDouble() * 10;
                myArray[i].I = r.NextDouble() * 10;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // We perform some first operation to ensure JIT compiled and optimized everything before running the real test.

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            Complex[] tmp = new Complex[2];
            for (int repeat = 0; repeat < 10; ++repeat)
            {
                sw.Start();
                tmp[0] = new Complex() { R = 10, I = 20 };
                tmp[1] = new Complex() { R = 30, I = 50 };
                ComplexComparer.Default.Compare(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
                tmp.OrderByDescending(c => c.ModulusSquared()).ToArray();
                sw.Stop();
            }

            int[] testSizes = new int[] { 5, 100, 1000, 100000, 250000, 1000000 };

            for (int testSizeIdx = 0; testSizeIdx < testSizes.Length; ++testSizeIdx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("For " + testSizes[testSizeIdx].ToString() + " input ...");

                // We create our big array

                Complex[] myArray = new Complex[testSizes[testSizeIdx]];

                double bestTime = double.MaxValue;

                // Now we execute repeatCount times our test.

                const int repeatCount = 15;

                for (int repeat = 0; repeat < repeatCount; ++repeat)
                {
                    // We fill our array with random data

                    RandomComplexArray(myArray);

                    // Now we perform our sorting.

                    sw.Reset();
                    sw.Start();
                    Array.Sort(myArray, ComplexComparer.Default);
                    sw.Stop();

                    double elapsed = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
                    if (elapsed < bestTime)
                        bestTime = elapsed;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Array.Sort best time is " + bestTime.ToString());

                // Now we perform our test using linq
bestTime = double.MaxValue; // i forgot this before
                for (int repeat = 0; repeat < repeatCount; ++repeat)
                {
                    // We fill our array with random data

                    RandomComplexArray(myArray);

                    // Now we perform our sorting.

                    sw.Reset();
                    sw.Start();
                    myArray = myArray.OrderByDescending(c => c.ModulusSquared()).ToArray();
                    sw.Stop();

                    double elapsed = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
                    if (elapsed < bestTime)
                        bestTime = elapsed;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("linq best time is " + bestTime.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And here the results:

```
For 5 input ...
Array.Sort best time is 0,0004
linq best time is 0,0018

For 100 input ...
Array.Sort best time is 0,0267
linq best time is 0,0298

For 1000 input ...
Array.Sort best time is 0,3568
linq best time is 0,4107

For 100000 input ...
Array.Sort best time is 57,3536
linq best time is 64,0196

For 250000 input ...
Array.Sort best time is 157,8832
linq best time is 194,3723

For 1000000 input ...
Array.Sort best time is 692,8211
linq best time is 1058,3259

Press enter to quit.
```

My machine is an Intel I5, 64 bit windows seven.
Sorry! I did a small stupid bug in the previous edit!
ARRAY.SORT OUTPEFORMS LINQ, yes by a very small amount, but as suspected, this amount grows with n, seems in a not-so-linear way. It seems to me both code overhead and a memory problem (cache miss, object allocation, GC ... don't know).

Comment: The LINQ version will only compute the Modulus once for each value, while your version computes the ModulusSqured for both values every time they are compared. I suspect that the performance will not be significantly different between your two versions. I also suspect that it is possible that the LINQ version may outperform yours for some sizes of input. In this case, there is no way to know without trying it out both ways.

Comment: May be you are right, but of course, sorting an array is O(n * log n), so there are exactly n * log n (r * r + i * i) operation. Since this operation by modern processors is really fast i really don't know what in reality will be faster. We should run a complex and long test.

Answer (score 0):

```
public struct Complex: IComparable<Complex>
{
   //complex rectangular number: a + bi
   public decimal A
   public decimal B
   //synonymous with absolute value, or in geometric terms, distance
   public decimal Modulus() { ... }

   //CompareTo() is the default comparison used by most built-in sorts;
   //all we have to do here is pass through to Decimal's IComparable implementation
   //via the results of the Modulus() methods
   public int CompareTo(Complex other){ return this.Modulus().CompareTo(other.Modulus()); }

}
```

You can now use any sorting method you choose on any collection of Complex instances; Array.Sort(), List.Sort(), Enumerable.OrderBy() (it doesn't use your IComparable, but if Complex were a member of a containing class you could sort the containing class by the Complex members without having to go the extra level down to comparing moduli), etc etc.

You stated you wanted to sort in descending order; you may consider multiplying the results of the Modulus() comparison by -1 before returning it. However, I would caution against this as it may be confusing; you would have to use a method that normally gives you descending order to get the list in ascending order. Instead, most sorting methods allow you to specify either a sorting direction, or a custom comparison which can still make use of the IComparable implementation:

```
//This will use your Comparison, but reverse the sort order based on its result
myEnumerableOfComplex.OrderByDescending(c=>c);
//This explicitly negates your comparison; you can also use b.CompareTo(a)
//which is equivalent
myListOfComplex.Sort((a,b) => return a.CompareTo(b) * -1); 
//DataGridView objects use a SortDirection enumeration to control and report
//sort order
myGridViewOfComplex.Sort(myGridViewOfComplex.Columns["ComplexColumn"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use SortedList :) Assuming modulus is int:

```
var complexNumbers = new SortedList<int, Complex>();
complexNumbers.Add(number.Modulus(), number);
```